# How to perform an action when the state goes to the just previous state in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.I want to perform a certain action when the user clicks on the back button of the browser and the state goes back to the previous state.

I used below code to do that ,but that doesn't get called when back button of browser is clicked.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    console.log("scope.on called ");
    console.log($scope.viewTest.context.showMore)
    $scope.viewTest.context.showMore = true;
    console.log($scope.viewTest.context.showMore);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ui-routing, you can use the code below

```
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) 
    {
       if (toState.name === $rootScope.previousState )
       { 
           // u can any 1 or all of below 3 statements
           event.preventDefault();  // to Disable the event
           //Do whatever you want

        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to perform an action when the state of $scope changes not the $rootScope.

Comment: First of all, with the above code you are able to "catch" everywhere the back button "action".Also, you're loosing the $scope variables because in Angular a controller is not a singleton. There will be a new instance of it generated when you navigate back.
If you want to store any kind of variables between route-changes, you can create a service to do it.